# Send mail from Mac/Xampp with php

Tags: email

years ago, I was able to send email with php mail() function from my localhost. Today, noI try to reconfigure my macOS 10.12.1 with Xampp 1.7.3. I spent hours doing google search. I haven't found one that really focus on Mac/Xampp. Many of them are for Windows, which does not apply to my set up obviously. I followed some tutorials to modify the php.ini and others to modify /etc/postfix/main.cf etc. Sadly it was all lost causes. I am all confused now, just how many files are needed to get php mail() working? Thanks in advance.